# scheduled timer with CoreMotion

Tags: swift, timer, scheduled-tasks, core-motion

I'm using the CoreMotion framework, and it works, but now I'd like to add a timer that loads a method after 5 seconds.

If 5 seconds have not passed load another method.

the problem is that in the debug area it doesn't print "STOPMAP" or "STARTMAP" so I think the timer doesn't work, where am I wrong?

```
import UIKit

import CoreMotion

private let motionActivityManager = CMMotionActivityManager()

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblActivity: UILabel!
    
    var second = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
           let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(calculateSeconds), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        
        motionActivityManager.startActivityUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) { (activity: CMMotionActivity?) in
            guard let activity = activity else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if activity.stationary {
                    self.lblActivity.text = "Stationary"
                    print("Stationary")
                    
                    calculate()

                } else if activity.walking {
                    self.lblActivity.text = "Walking"
                    print("Walking")
                } else if activity.running {
                    self.lblActivity.text = "Running"
                    print("Running")
                } else if activity.automotive {
                    self.lblActivity.text = "Automotive"
                    print("Automotive")
                }
            }
        }
        
        
    }
    
    @objc func calculateSeconds() {
         second += 1
    }
    
    func calculate() {
         if second > 5 {
             stopMap()
         } else {
             startMap()
         }

         second = 0
         timer.invalidate()
         timer = nil
    }
    
    func stopMap() {
        print("STOPMAP")
    }
    
    func startMap() {
        print("STARTMAP")
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post your debug output? Also, which timer are you referring to in `calculate()`? Your code does not compile because timer is not defined in `calculate()`.

Comment: Your code has multiple problems. As Rob C points out, it won't compile because you did not make timer an instance variable. Your function `calculate()` appears to only be called once, and it will kill the timer as soon as it is run.

Comment: Also, you should not increment a counter each time a timer fires in order to count elapsed time. Instead you should record the Date when the timer is started and then use the current Date when the timer fires and compute the difference. (Timers may "miss a beat" if your app is busy in synchronous code at the point it is supposed to fire, and then can also drift over time, causing increasing differences between the amount of actual elapsed time  and your seconds counter.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, this will resolve the issue of timer.
Test it on real device.

```
import CoreMotion

import UIKit

private let motionActivityManager = CMMotionActivityManager()

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var second = 0
    var timer: Timer?

    public func addTimer() {
        motionActivityManager.startActivityUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) { (activity: CMMotionActivity?) in
            guard let activity = activity else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(activity)
                if activity.stationary {
                    print("Stationary")

                    // Add a 5-second timer when the activity becomes "Stationary"
                    self.startTimer()
                } else if activity.walking {
                    print("Walking")
                    // Stop the timer when the activity changes
                    self.stopTimer()
                } else if activity.running {
                    print("Running")
                    // Stop the timer when the activity changes
                    self.stopTimer()
                } else if activity.automotive {
                    print("Automotive")
                    // Stop the timer when the activity changes
                    self.stopTimer()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func updateTimer() {
        second += 1
        if second >= 5 {
            // Execute your action when the timer reaches 5 seconds
            self.timerFired()
        }
    }

    func startTimer() {
        // Create a 1-second repeating timer
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func stopTimer() {
        // Stop and invalidate the timer
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
        second = 0
    }

    func timerFired() {
        // Implement the action you want to take when the timer fires (after 5 seconds)
        print("Timer fired after 5 seconds!")
        // You can add your logic here, such as stopping the activity updates.
        // For example, self.motionActivityManager.stopActivityUpdates()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting! Please [edit] to add a short explanation of your solution.